# Motion in one dimension. One car overtaking a different one

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I stumbled upon this exercise:
[image]

From this [book](http://www.simardartizanfarm.ca/pdf/1000-Solved-Problems-in-Classical-Physics-An-Exercise-EBook.pdf).

The problem I have is that I cannot understand author's mathematics from the solution:
[image]

Precisely: what did he do in the step *"Eliminating t between the two equations"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small supplement to the solution in the book:

With start time $t_0 = 0$ the truck and car reached a distance

$s_{truck} = ut  \ \ \ $ (0.1)

and

$s_{car} = 1/2 a t^2 \ \ \  $ (0.2)

w.r.t. the starting location after time $t$. We want to look at both distances $s_{truck}$ and $s_{car}$ at the same time. Therefore we can solve (0.1) for $t$ and plug that into (0.2). That is meant by "Eliminating $t$ between the two equations". This yields

$s_{car} = 1/2 a (s_{truck}/u)^2.\ \ \ $ (0.3)

Since we want to know the distance after which the car caught up with the truck we get another condition: $s_{truck}=s_{car}$. Using this condition in Eq. (0.3) yields Eq. (3) from the exercise, which can be solved for $s=s_{car}=s_{truck}$.

Answer (score 1):

From equation (1) we have

$t =\frac s u$

Substituting for $t$ in equation (2) gives

$s = \frac 1 2 \frac {as^2}{u^2}$

Rearranging this gives equation (3).